# Prefetching and yielding to "hide" cache misses in rust

Tags: rust, async-await, coroutine

When C++20 got stackless coroutines [some](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.14778/3236187.3236216) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15981) successfully used them to "hide" cache misses via prefetching and switching to another coroutine. As far as I can tell rust's async is also like stackless coroutines in that it is a "zero cost abstraction". Is there work similar to the ones I mentioned for implementing such techniques in rust? If not is there is anything fundamentally preventing one from doing something like that with async/await?

Edit: I wanted to give a very high level and simplified summary of what I understand that the papers propose:

we want to run a bunch of independent processes that look like the following

```
P1 = load1;proc1; load1';proc1'; load1'';proc1''; ... 
P2 = load2;proc2; load2';proc2'; load2'';proc2''; ... 
...
PN = loadN;procN; loadN';procN'; loadN'';procN''; ...
```

where all the `loadI` terms are likely to cause a cache miss. The authors leverage coroutines to (dynamically) interleave the processes so that the code executed looks like the following:

```
P = 

prefetch1;prefetch2;...;prefetchN;
load1;proc1;prefetch1'; # yield to the scheduler
load2;proc2;prefetch2'; # yield to the scheduler
...
loadN;procN;prefetchN'; # yield to the scheduler
load1';proc1';prefetch1''; # yield to the scheduler
load2';proc2';prefetch2''; # yield to the scheduler

...
loadN';procN';prefetchN''; # yield to the scheduler
...
```

Comment: This is really fascinating! No idea if there is existing work for this but I don't see why it wouldn't be possible; see `std::intrinsics::prefetch_*`

Comment: I'm not sure [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43122#issuecomment-716256938=) is directly related, but there may be some performance-relevant things that C++ coroutines do differently from rust's generators.

Comment: @Caesar I don't know match about coroutines in C++, but from what I understand they are always (unless optimized) allocated on the heap, while Rust generators are allocated on the stack. Of course this is an advantage to Rust :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full code for this post can be found [here.](https://github.com/Aiden2207/prefetch)

I didn't look super hard, but as far as I'm aware there is no existing research on the topic, so I decided to do a little bit of it myself. Unlike the mentioned papers, I took a simple approach to test if it was possible by creating a couple of simple linked lists and summing them:

```rust
pub enum List<T> {
    Cons(T, Box<List<T>>),
    Nil,
}
impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> Self {
        let mut tail = List::Nil;
        for item in iter {
            tail = List::Cons(item, Box::new(tail));
        }
        tail
    }
}
const END: i32 = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 16;
fn gen_lists() -> (List<i32>, List<i32>) {
    let range = 1..=END;
    (List::new(range.clone()), List::new(range))
}
```

Ok, a couple of big simple linked lists. I ran nine different algorithms in two different benchmarks to see how the prefetching affected things. The benchmarks are summing the lists in an owned fashion, where the list is destroyed during iteration,  causing deallocation to be the bulk of the measured time, and summing them in a borrowed fashion, where the deallocation time is not measured. The various algorithms tested are really only three different algorithms implemented with three different techniques, Iterators, [`Generators`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html), and async [`Streams`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html).

The three algorithms are zip, which is iterating over both lists in lockstep, chain, which is iterating over the lists one after the other, and zip prefetch, where the prefetch and switch method is used while zipping the two lists together. The basic iterator looks like this:

```rust
pub struct ListIter<T>(List<T>);
impl<T> Iterator for ListIter<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut temp = List::Nil;
        std::mem::swap(&mut temp, &mut self.0);
        match temp {
            List::Cons(t, next) => {
                self.0 = *next;
                Some(t)
            }
            List::Nil => None,
        }
    }
}
```

and the version with prefetching looks like this:

```rust
pub struct ListIterPrefetch<T>(List<T>);
impl<T> Iterator for ListIterPrefetch<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut temp = List::Nil;
        std::mem::swap(&mut temp, &mut self.0);
        match temp {
            List::Cons(t, next) => {
                self.0 = *next;
                if let List::Cons(_, next) = &self.0 {
                    unsafe { prefetch_read_data::<List<T>>(&**next, 3) }
                }
                Some(t)
            }
            List::Nil => None,
        }
    }
}
```

There are also different implementations for Generators and Streams, as well as a version that operates over references but they all look pretty much the same, so I am omitting them for brevity. The test harness is pretty simple- it just takes in a name-function pair and times it:

```rust
type BenchFn<T> = fn(List<T>, List<T>) -> T;
fn bench(funcs: &[(&str, BenchFn<i32>)]) {
    for (s, f) in funcs {
        let (l, r) = gen_lists();
        let now = Instant::now();
        println!("bench: {s} result: {} time: {:?}", f(l, r), now.elapsed());
    }
}
```

For example, usage with the basic iterator tests:

```rust
bench(&[
    ("iter::zip", |l, r| {
        l.into_iter().zip(r).fold(0, |a, (l, r)| a + l + r)
    }),
    ("iter::zip prefetch", |l, r| {
        l.into_iter_prefetch()
            .zip(r.into_iter_prefetch())
            .fold(0, |a, (l, r)| a + l + r)
    }),
    ("iter::chain", |l, r| l.into_iter().chain(r).sum()),
]);
```

The results of the test on my computer, which is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU with 24 Gb of RAM:

```
Bench owned
bench: iter::zip result: 67108864 time: 11.1873901s
bench: iter::zip prefetch result: 67108864 time: 19.3889487s
bench: iter::chain result: 67108864 time: 8.4363853s
bench: generator zip result: 67108864 time: 16.7242197s
bench: generator chain result: 67108864 time: 8.9897788s
bench: generator prefetch result: 67108864 time: 11.7599589s
bench: stream::zip result: 67108864 time: 14.339864s
bench: stream::chain result: 67108864 time: 7.7592133s
bench: stream::zip prefetch result: 67108864 time: 11.1455706s
Bench ref
bench: iter::zip result: 67108864 time: 1.1343996s
bench: iter::zip prefetch result: 67108864 time: 864.4865ms
bench: iter::chain result: 67108864 time: 1.4036277s
bench: generator zip result: 67108864 time: 1.1360857s
bench: generator chain result: 67108864 time: 1.740029s
bench: generator prefetch result: 67108864 time: 904.1086ms
bench: stream::zip result: 67108864 time: 1.0902568s
bench: stream::chain result: 67108864 time: 1.5683112s
bench: stream::zip prefetch result: 67108864 time: 1.2031745s
```

The result is the sum calculated, and time was the recorded time. When looking at the destructive summation benchmarks, a few things stand out:

- The chain algorithm works the best. My guess is this is because this method improves cache locality for the allocator, which is where the vast majority of the time is spent.
- Prefetching greatly improves the time with the Stream and generator versions, bring their times on par with the standard iterator.
- Prefetching completely ruins the iterator strategy. This is why you always benchmark when doing these things. I also would not be surprised if this is a failure by the compiler to optimize properly, rather than the prefetching directly hurting performance.

When looking at the borrowing summation a few things stand out:

- Without measuring deallocation times, the recorded times are much shorter. This is how I know deallocation is most of the above benchmark.
- The chain method loses- apparently running in lockstep is the way to go.
- Prefetching is the way to go for iterators and generators. In contrast to the previous benchmark, prefetching causes the iterator to be the fastest strategy, rather than the slowest.
- Prefetching causes a slow down when using streams, although the streams just performed poorly overall.

This testing wasn't the most scientific, for a variety reasons, and isn't for a particularly realistic workload, but given the results I can confidantly say that a prefetch and switch strategy can definitely result in solid performance improvements if done right. I also omitted a fair bit of the testing code for brevity, and the full code can be found [here.](https://github.com/Aiden2207/prefetch)

Comment: Thanks for putting in all this effort, this is great example code. I think the way you structured it the comparison may be a bit unfair in favour of the non-prefetching case because it seems to me that a) the items of the lists are likely to be allocated next to each other helping the hardware prefetcher catch on to the pattern and b) hopefully `fold(0, |a, (l, r)| a + l + r)` generates few enough instructions that the processor's ROB is likely able to stochastically prefetch the future instructions. Given these I am actually pleasantly surprised at how well the prefetching bench does.

Comment: Another way in which I think you are doing a disservice to the prefetching case is that I can't seem to get how you are actually interleaving the prefetching coroutines. It looks like your code doesn't do enough work after each prefetch to let the cache line arrive at L1 before it is loaded to a register. (I edited my question to include a brief overview of the papers' ideas just as a reality check)

Comment: @fakedrake the interleaving is done within the `zip` method calls. By forcing the iterators to advance in lockstep, it necessarily alternates between the two. I doubt the allocations are contiguous, mainly because the allocator is taking ~2.5Gb of memory for itself. Although, I have no clue how much work per coroutine is ideal, so there is a good chance I missed that target.